# Google analytics dataset restart from scratch

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, dataset

I deleted my google analytics complete dataset in bigquery by mistake :-(
Is it possible to restart it from scratch, in the same way when you linked for the first time in GA admin, in order to rebuild the complete dataset with all day tables ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you delete the dataset as well as the tables, or just the tables? It is possible to "undelete" tables in BigQuery up to seven days afterward, but if you delete the dataset as well, you lose that ability.

Comment: I deleted the dataset (and all tables)

Comment: As per documentation it's not possible if you deleted the whole dataset ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable I'd recommend to get in contact with Google Analytics to re-export the tables

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Elliott Brossard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253347/elliott-brossard) and [Martin Weitzmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6532822/martin-weitzmann), it is seems that you can just restore a table within 2 days of deletion; however, you cannot reference a deleted table if the encapsulating dataset was also deleted/recreated since the table deletion event, based on the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable).

I suggest you to take a look on this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9026876?hl=en) that contains the **How to get support** guide that you can follow to contact to the Analytics support team in order to check the available options to re-create your GA tables, as well as this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089), where you can find the instructions required to export your GA data to BigQuery.